# AG Grid Community styles not loading properly in Next.js production build until page refresh

Tags: next.js, ag-grid-react, next.js14

I'm encountering an issue with AG Grid Community version integrated into a Next.js application. When navigating to the grid page in production, the styles of the grid aren't loading correctly. However, upon manually refreshing the page, the styles appear as expected.

React - 18
Nextjs - 14.0.3
"ag-grid-react": "^31.0.1",
"@ag-grid-community/react": "^31.0.1",
"@ag-grid-community/styles": "^31.0.1",

I've ensured that the integration is set up properly, yet the initial rendering seems to miss the necessary styles. Is there a specific setup or workaround within Next.js to ensure the AG Grid styles load consistently upon page navigation in a production environment without requiring a manual refresh?

I made attempts to resolve the issue by adjusting the CSS import location and changing the AG Grid theme from 'ag-theme-quartz' to other available themes. Despite these changes, the problem persists, and the styles only load properly after manually refreshing the page.

Any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the css and theme imports on the main layout.js and it will load properly (not a very clean solution but it worked for me)